# How can my C program check if it has execution permission on a given file?

Tags: c, linux, permissions, execution

Is there a way to determine if the process *may* execute a file without having to actually execute it (e.g. by calling `execv(filepath, args)` only to fail and discover that `errno == EACCES`)?

I could `stat` the file and observe `st_mode`, but then I still don’t know how that pertains to the process.

Ideally, I’m looking for a function along the lines of

```
get_me_permissions(filepath, &status); // me: the process calling this function
// when decoded, status tells if the process can read, write, and/or execute 
// the file given by filepath.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows, Linux, or Mac?

Comment: @Nick: Linux - check the tags :)

Comment: Note that whatever method you use, be aware of the potential race hazard.  If something else changes the file permissions *after* you check them, and *before* you attempt to execute the file, you will have problems!

Comment: @Oli: that's usually solved by ensuring that there's a long enough period between the two that the race seems "natural". For instance, if you want to list all executable files then you use the file permissions - they might have changed by the time someone acts on the information, and that's expected. If you're planning to execute it immediately then there's usually no point checking, just do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://linux.die.net/man/2/access

Note the slight tricksiness around suid - if the process has effective superuser privilege it isn't taken into account, since the general idea of the function is to check whether the original invoking user *should* have access to the file, not to check whether this process *could* access the file.

Comment: In particular, use the `X_OK` mode.

Comment: Downvoted because it's critical that @R..'s answer stand out.

Comment: @Matt: if you think so, but R..'s answer is contains two incorrect statements, followed by a speculation about the questioner's code (namely that the questioner is planning to actually execute anything) that is already adequately covered by Oli's comment on the question. There is of course an obvious way to misuse `access`, but it's flat wrong to say that it's never useful to look at current permissions. If I'm writing a file manager, and I want to highlight programs executable by the current user, I'm supposed to run each file and check for EACCES? Don't think so.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, folks. `access` is exactly what I need, though I do plan to handle errors where I intend to call `execve`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your end goal is to eventually execute the program, you don't. This test would be useless because the result is potentially wrong even before the function to make the check returns! You must be prepared to handle failure of `execve` due to permission errors.

As pointed out by Steve Jessop, checking whether a given file is executable *can* be useful in some situations, such as a file listing (`ls -l`) or visual file manager. One could certainly think of more esoteric uses such a using the permission bits of a file for inter-process communication (interesting as a method which would not require any resource allocation), but I suspect `stat` ("What are the permission bits set to?") rather than `access` ("Does the calling process have X permission?") is more likely to be the interesting question...

Comment: You could say the same thing about `ls` - the files it lists might have disappeared or changed by the time it prints their names to stdout. One must of course be cautious of this issue when using `ls`, nevertheless `ls` is not "useless".

Comment: @mark4o: The Wikipedia article you linked seems to have some misleading information in the "preventing" section, but I don't feel unbiased enough to fix it. Specifically, it pushes exceptions as a solution, when any means of attempting the operation and checking for failure works just fine, and regarding the impossibility result, it does not make it clear that this result is purely in regards to `access` and similar methods of decoupling check and use, and that the aforementioned solution is not affected by the impossibility result.